# Displaying images with a horizontal scroll bar in a progressive web app

Tags: html, css, django, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to display images of apparels category wise. So I have apparels from kurtis, jeans, saree and tops. So these categories has to be displayed vertically one after the other and the images belonging to individual categories has to be displayed horizontally with a scroll bar. And each of the images when hovered over should display its attributes. All these are happening in a progressive web app with Django backend with HTML, CSS interface.

views.py

```
@login_required
def viewall(request):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    images = Images.objects.all().order_by('-id')
    return render_to_response('cms/view-all.html',{'images':images,'media_url':settings.MEDIA_URL,'categories':categories,},context)
```

view-all.html

```
{% extends "cms/base.html" %}

{% block title %}
    View-all
{% endblock %}

{% block main %}
<style>
*{box-sizing: border-box;}

.wrapper{ 
    overflow-x:scroll;     
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.container {
    background: #ccc;
    position: relative;
    height: 50%;
    width: 75%;
    max-width: 75%;
    display: inline-block;
}
img {
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto auto 0;
    height: 20%;
    width: 75%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    max-height: 50%;
    max-width: 100%;
   }
.overlay {
    position: absolute; 
    bottom: 0; 
    background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    color: #f1f1f1; 
    width: 75%;
    transition: .5s ease;
    opacity:0;
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
   }
.container:hover .overlay {
    opacity: 1;
}
</style>
{% for category in categories %}
<br /><h3>{{ category.name }}</h3> 
<div class="wrapper">   
    <div id="slider4" class="text-center">
        {%  for image in images %}
        {% ifequal image.category category %}
        <div class="container">
            <img src="{{ image.file.url }}">
            <div class="overlay">Category: {{ image.category }}<br />
                                 Manufacturer: {{ image.manufacturer }}<br />
                                 Location: {{ image.manufacturer.location }}<br />
                                 Cost price: {{ image.cost_price }}<br />
                                 Sales price: {{ image.selling_price }}<br />
            </div>
            <br />
        </div>
        {% endifequal %}
        {% endfor %}  
    </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

But the problem is that

1. Images aren't retaining their original dimension ratio. How do I maintain original dimension ratio?
2. Hovering over one image displays attributes of all images. Why is this happening?
3. The page isn't fitting device-width when viewed on a mobile phone.

This might be simple CSS errors but I'm a newbie in CSS. Please help.

Comment: Why doesn't anyone answer? Is this a long question or hard question that everyone ignores?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Try adding `max-width: 100%;` to the images and ensure they're not being given an explicit height or a max-height for that matter.
2. That's not easily answerable without seeing the code in action. There are a million and one reasons why this could be happening, but it's not clear why from the markup you've provided.
3. Is that to say there is white-space to the right side of the screen? If so, try deleting sections from the DOM in Dev Tools until the issue is gone to help you narrow down where the isue is.

Comment: For 2. should I share anything else to make it more clear?

Comment: I don't think so, or at least not that I can think of. The issue is we cannot see exactly how the items are being rendered, which will be what part of the issue is. Perhaps try this, for the sake of eliminating some factors; change `.container:hover .overlay` to `.container:hover > .overlay`. Very unlikely to change anything, but I have a curious thought.

Comment: Also try adding `display: none;` to `.overlay` and `display: block;` to the hovered state.

Comment: adding > helped. Thank you. Any idea on how can I adapt the size of hover box to the size of the image? Right now the hover box is big for a small size image.

Comment: Is that on desktop or mobile? The container is currently 75% width, you'd have to remove all the widths set on the container and it will adapt to the size of the image. Though you may have to make it `inline-block`.

Comment: The problem is on my mobile.

Comment: In which case do something like `@media only screen and (max-width : 767px) { height: auto; max-height: none; }`

Comment: Where should I put this?

Comment: At the bottom of the CSS file or in your case inside, at the bottom of the `<style>` tag

Comment: Okay, great. Thank you so much. You are God! :D